# Variables as properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Consider this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if ('mySuperProperty' in window) 
  {
    alert(window['mySuperProperty']);
  }
  var mySuperProperty = 1;
</script>
```

Condition in if statement evaluates to true even though mySuperProperty isn't set yet. Why?

[Try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/UZAqS/).

I stole this question from http://dfilatov.blogspot.com/2009/04/javascript.html (Russian)

Comment: WHy not check window.mySuperProperty? shorter and more readable imo.

Comment: Is that wrapped in a function or simply in <script> tags?

Comment: "Checking" window.mySuperProperty is different. If you mean executing something like "if (window.mySuperProperty) {}" then you would simply check for the value of the mySuperProperty variable (that is in this case a property of global object) and not for the existance of it.

Comment: I see no use to check for the very existance of a property in JavaScript imo as it is a dynamic programming language. What´s interesting is if a variable/property is not equal to undefined. As an experiment it´s interesting though.

Comment: This is a great example of why I move all var declarations to the top of scope in JavaScript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess this happens becuase: **the JS code gets first parsed and analyzed**. 
Variables and functions get instantiated at this time, but only during execution they will be assigned with their values used in declaratins. This is exactly why you get "undefined" in alert.

Comment: Right, this explains why "if (window.mySuperProperty)" returns false (because "mySuperProperty" has no value) but "if ('mySuperProperty' in window)" returns true (because "mySuperProperty" does exist).

Answer (score 1):

The expression "window.mySuperProperty" checks the value of the mySuperProperty, which is at the time of the alert *undefined*

On the other hand *mySuperProperty in window* checks if the window has the mySuperProperty, which is checked in the whole window namespace (after every property name has been set).

Therefor,

if ('mySuperProperty' in window) returns true > the variable exists, but has no value yet
if (window.mySuperProperty) returns false > undefined is a Falsy value.